# How to find recent values inside a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of `dates` with a format %y-%m-%d and a single `value`. I need to find all the dates that are more recent than value

```
dates = ['22-02-10','22-02-11','22-02-12','22-02-13','22-02-14','22-02-15']
value = '22-02-12'
```

the output should be false,false,false,true,true,true.
How can I perform this in a fast way without a for loop?

Comment: You can *hide* the loop with something like `map` but in the end you always have to loop over the contents of the list to actually check them

Comment: list comprehension could also work, but that would be a loop as well...

Comment: if your list is ordered, then I'm sure there are some real fancy methods to find the cutoff date and find some efficiencies. but if it isn't ordered, you'd have to order it

Comment: @Gaetano Veti You ask for a fast way but now accepted a slow one (the NumPy one). Why? Is it because they falsely claimed that it's fast?

Comment: @KellyBundy it is because i do not have the tools to determine what is fast in terms of computation and what is not. I needed a fast to write solution. I'm open to better solutions btw

Comment: Could you also respond to @scotscotmcc's implicit question about whether your list is sorted?

Comment: And how long is the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy to let the underlying c implementation do the looping (which is way faster then pure python)

```
import numpy as np
dates = ['22-02-10','22-02-11','22-02-12','22-02-13','22-02-14','22-02-15']
value = '22-02-12'
dates = np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64')
value = np.array(value, dtype='datetime64')
print(dates > value)
```

Comment: the `==` should be `>`

Comment: sorry, made the correction

Comment: The output is correct with `>`: [False False False  True  True  True]

Comment: *"way faster then pure python"* - Please share your benchmark results and code, as that's the opposite of what mine shows.

Comment: For the proposed case the problem size is is too smal to make significant difference and the overhead of converting to numpy format is big, for bigger sizes numpy can make huge differences, you can consult many online benchmarks that show that this class of operations behaves significantly better then classical python

Comment: You can see I've already benchmarked with a list 10000 times longer and NumPy was still much *slower*. (I've actually also tested an a million times longer list, same result).

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward list comprehension:

```
output = [date > value for date in dates]
```

Benchmark results with the suggested NumPy solution:

```
len(dates) = 6:
Python is 6.6 times faster than NumPy
Python is 6.5 times faster than NumPy
Python is 7.0 times faster than NumPy

len(dates) = 600:
Python is 3.4 times faster than NumPy
Python is 3.5 times faster than NumPy
Python is 3.5 times faster than NumPy

len(dates) = 60000:
Python is 4.1 times faster than NumPy
Python is 4.0 times faster than NumPy
Python is 4.1 times faster than NumPy
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJBboMwELzzir0BVZIGkvaARJ9Q5Z5GlaPYxBIYyyyVUJS3U9vYdWlSKT7NemdnxgtywHMrNuPIVNsA8oZyBN7IVqGrIleJvpEDkA6EjKITQdpBCfs4z5frfJmt44WHWYB5gJsAtwG@xIfoi9Q91VphSOtTBiyxLguwhLSIQB9vLOSKKEUGzznhIGkZm8rEft3GqeV78R@@vfifryj2Sjibt2l8ilPdi@Poe9PydGCtsgLAndBhUtAIZyILs9QjVU5MKi4wYfGHqKmYiKmOfgnVtXAxjcWn0VdEVDTZOAVzkOmZ6dMlNWmOJ1L8XaX3LZ19mK1uZ6sHZ336nf2jgHdwQfaMVbHK2NWKdsBIh1QBnomA977ZDfo50Z21ZGt90l8deDJ3s/5te0ZIx/Eb)):

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

dates = ['22-02-10','22-02-11','22-02-12','22-02-13','22-02-14','22-02-15']
value = '22-02-12'

def f(dates, value):
    dates = np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64')
    value = np.array(value, dtype='datetime64')
    return dates > value

def g(dates, value):
    return [date > value for date in dates]

def test(dates, value, number):
    print(f'\nlen(dates) = {len(dates)}:')
    for _ in range(3):
        tf = timeit(lambda: f(dates, value), number=number)
        tg = timeit(lambda: g(dates, value), number=number)
        print(f'Python is {tf/tg:.1f} times faster than NumPy')

test(dates, value, 10000)
test(dates * 100, value, 1000)
test(dates * 10000, value, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say about **speed**, but maybe this could be a solution **without for loop** at all:

```
dates = ['22-02-10', '22-02-11', '22-02-12', '22-02-13', '22-02-14', '22-02-15']
value = '22-02-12'


def printing(the_list, element):
    if dates[element] < value or dates[element] == value:
        print("false")
        new_element = element + 1
        if new_element < len(the_list):
            printing(the_list, new_element)
    else:
        print("true")
        new_element = element + 1
        if new_element < len(the_list):
            printing(the_list, new_element)


printing(dates, 0)
```

What I am doing here is basically I am using **recursion** :D

*P.S.* I'm pretty sure there must some fancy super mega mathematic algorithm there, that can solve this with a much shorter code, and much faster, but... This is all my poor mind came up with :D

**UPDATE**

According to [this site](https://tio.run/##xVBLDoIwEN33FBM30AgJFN0YOAkhhIRBmtRCoGg8fa18StUDOKuXmfdr@6dqO5loXVcKR8gg9xgLIxbGkRfAhmMHMwcnDj45@OwV5F6JCY3hriOE1NhAP3CpuLz6qsVS8FEFgAJvKBW9EDDDG5jb5Ou6gBQWt274vmTZclqU75nt/UNTiREP1K4lPspVZUpt6AixZZhYl5SCQGk70j3Ahny@wdEuqWgK/NRSw/S/VoRYxvyNAURU6xc) my code is 3 times faster than other NumPy answer's code. So I'm proud of myself :D

My code gives: 0.030 s. to run

The NumPy code: 0.126 s. to run

Comment: @KellyBundy By the way, I can't write under your answer, due to my reputation level, so... You are still using for loop in your code, so technically your answer is wrong.

Comment: Now I see your code, but no benchmark. Are you just looking at the execution time of the script? That's very misleading.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do). I just took the other guy's code, and mine and ran them. My code is faster in this particular example.

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "loop". I believe most of the time, people actually mean a `for` statement or `while` statement, and most of the time when people ask for a solution without a loop, they're under the wrong impression that "loop" means slow.

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure that this guy was just looking for someone to do his homework :D. So his teacher probably told him to solve the case without for statement. This is my opinion, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: That's not a proper way to measure. With the NumPy one, you're mostly measuring not their actual solution but the `import numpy`, which is not interesting.

Comment: NumPy still uses for? :D And I don't. :D

Comment: And again, please read the post scriptum of my answer:D